# kill the [in-the-wild] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

I was surprised to see the tag [in-the-wild](/questions/tagged/in-the-wild), and was not surprised to see just 5 questions attached to it. Is it useful enough to keep?

Comment: Just edit/retag the questions

Comment: Removed the tag from the 5 questions. Give it a day or so to get deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [production](/questions/tagged/production) tag with 328 questions, I'm making this one a synonym of that so it doesn't return.

Oh, by the way, we have [production](/questions/tagged/production), [production-environment](/questions/tagged/production-environment) and [production-code](/questions/tagged/production-code) that also need examining. I love it when these little gems point down a rabbit hole :)

Comment: Call Trogodor!!

Comment: [tag:production-code] should likely be synonym of [tag:production]... it has just 8 questions

Comment: IIRC, there are IDEs and other toolkits that expressly call out the term "production environment" as official jargon.  It might not be safe to synonymize it.